# TinyMCE Uncaught ReferenceError: ext is not defined

Tags: google-chrome, tinymce, cdn, tinymce-4

I am including tinyMCE from CDN using this simple code:

```
$('head').append('<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.0/tinymce.min.js"></script>');
tinymce.init({selector: '#selector_id'});
```

It works fine without any warnings/errors in most browsers (FF, IE, Opera)
In Chrome it works too, but console shows this error: 'Uncaught ReferenceError: ext is not defined - include.postload.js:539'.

I tried including different available versions (4, 4.0, 4.1), but error persits. 
I also tried to include script directly in header, without JS, but it didn't help either.

What can be the reason for that error? and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a [bug](https://issues.adblockplus.org/ticket/1370) in Adblock Plus, closed 3 days ago, so hopefully the fix will be available soon. It was mentioned on a [forum](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25507) that the problem persists even when ABP is disabled, which is a bit disappointing.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an Ad-Blocker (e.g. Adblock Plus)?

I had the same error and got rid of it when I temporarily deactivated the browser extension.

I assume from time to time these extensions have problems with new browser versions
[(e.g. here)](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=19988).

Comment: Yes, I have read about possible interference with Adblock and tried to deactivate it, but it didn't help. Thanks for your reply in either case

Comment: Just had this issue today using TinyMCE in Umbraco 7. Disabling AdBlock Plus fixed it.